# search form on different page for Google Maps

Tags: wordpress, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to have a search form on every page of my WordPress site, in the header.php for instance, that contains a search form for Google Maps? When someone adds their postcode into the box they get redirected to the search results page which shows their results.

If so, does anyone know how this works or can anyone provide any code?

Many thanks

M

Comment: Does anyone else know how this is done?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite possible, and is described [here in google's API.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/imageapis/)  You can redirect the user using data gathered by your form, or you can actually even embed a map into your own webpage (which seems like a better user experience, and lets the user spend more time on your site).

Comment: Thanks HackyStack, what i am looking for is for the user to add a postcode on one page which then goes to a results page which shows the maps in a store locator format. Do you know of the code that i can use for the search input form?